# Segmentation fault deleting node

Tags: c, struct, gdb, nodes

I am getting a `segmentation fault` when I am trying to delete a movie from my movie database. I can not figure out why ?

I ran the program with gdb and I am getting a segmentation fault right here:

```
 (previousNode->next)->previous = previousNode;
```

Any suggestions as to why I am getting a problem here ?

Comment: Bravo for using `gdb`. But you should use it more extensively (e.g. use its `backtrace`, `display`, `print`, `watch` etc... commands). Also use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/); perhaps `previousNode->next` is `NULL`... (check inside `gdb` using `print`)

Comment: Are you sure you want `free(title);`? What if the caller passes in a literal string, or a string from an array? Then it haven't been allocated by `malloc` and can't be free'd.

Comment: That is correct. It is NULL. How can I fix it ? any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

(previousNode->next)->previous = previousNode; // segmentation fault

If your list size is two and you are deleting the 2nd node , then this will cause error , as you `previousNode->next`will be Null , so `(previousNode->next)->previous` will become `(NULL)->previous` which is error.

Do like this :

```
if(previousNode->next!=NULL)
  (previousNode->next)->previous = previousNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

What if the node you try to delete is the last? Then `currentNode->next` (and therefore `previousNode->next`) will be `NULL` and you try to access a `NULL` pointer leading to undefined behavior and probable crash.

You fix this by simple checking if `previousNode->next` is `NULL` or not before dereferencing it.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have a null pointer, but it could also be a bad pointer.

Since you are running gdb, you can print things.  Print some stuff and see what you can figure out.

From the GDB prompt:

```
p previousNode
```

Is `previousNode` a null pointer?  If not:

```
p previousNode->next
```

How about now, is that a null pointer?

Any time you apply the `->` operator to a null pointer, you get a seg fault error.

Another thing to try: set a breakpoint in the function that allocates nodes, and try printing node addresses.  For example, I just wrote a trivial C program that called `malloc()` and the resulting address was `0x17b0010`. If I printed a variable like `previousNode` and it was something similar like `0x17b01000` then that looks plausible; if it was something like `0xdcdcdcdc` that's not plausible.  Whatever that address might be, it's probably not from my program (more likely it's not a valid pointer at all).

And I second the recommendation for Valgrind.  It can find all sorts of subtle mistakes you might make with `malloc()` and `free()`.

One more idea: you can add a member to your node struct, a member that is just used for "sanity checks".  I often add a member called `sig` (short for "signature") and it contains a different value in each of my structs.  Then code that works with a struct can check the `sig` value and, if it is not set correctly, there must be some sort of error.  For example:

```
if (!previousNode || !previousNode->next || previousNode->sig != NODE_SIG_VALUE)
{
    return ERROR_CODE_BAD_NODE;
}
else
{
    (previousNode->next)->previous = previousNode;
    return 0; /* SUCCESS */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're deleting a movie, I suppose, you're deleting reference to current element from previous element and, then, dereferencing it (we would need to see previous source lines to be sure). This would explain why `previousNode->next` is `NULL`. Best way to fix this is by dereferencing before deleting this is:

```
node* oldPrevious = NULL;

if(previousNode && previousNode->next)
{
   oldPrevious = (previousNode->next)->previous;
   (previousNode->next)->previous = previousNode;
}

if(oldPrevious)
   free(oldPrevious);
```